# Add button to table row which is linked to the data on that row

Tags: php, html, button, html-table, row

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I'm using the code below to create a table which lists `location records` for the `current user`.

```
<form name="locationsconsole" id="locationsconsole" method="post" action="locationsaction.php">
            <table width="865">
                    <tr>
                        <th width="22"></th>
                        <th width="236"><div align="left">Location Name</div></th>
                        <th width="244"><div align="left">Location Address</div></th>
                        <th width="71"></th>                                
                    </tr>   

                    <?php


                    $query = "SELECT  l.*, COUNT(f.locationid) totalfinds FROM detectinglocations l LEFT JOIN finds f ON f.locationid = l.locationid WHERE l.userid = '$idnum' GROUP BY l.locationname";
                    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('error');

                    while($obj=mysql_fetch_object($result))
                    {

                    ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="hidden" name="lid" value="<?php echo $obj->locationid;?>"/></td>
                        <td><?php echo $obj->locationname;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $obj->returnedaddress;?></td>
                        <td><input name="type" type="submit" value="View Details"/></td>
                    </tr>
                                <?php
                                    }   

                                ?>


              </table>
      </form>
```

You'll see that on each row there is a button which takes the user to another page via `locationsaction.php` which is listed below.

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['lid'] = $_POST['lid'];
if (isset($_POST['type'])) {
    $urls = array(
        'View Details' => 'viewlocation.php'
    );
    $url = $urls[$_POST['type']];
    header("Location: " . $url);
}
?>
```

There are currently 3 `location` records in the table which is correct, and when the button is clicked the user is taken to the correct screen.

However, the problem I'm having is that no matter which row I click the button on, the record retrieved is always related to the last `location` record.

I've been trying to sort this for quite some time now, and I've just not been able to find a solution, despite many page re-writes.

I just wondered whether someone could take a look at this please and let me know where I'm gong wrong.

Comment: I wouldn't mention this except that you said you just rewrote this code... You should really decouple your code, i.e. separate your data access routines from your html output.  Additionally, the `mysql_*` functions are essentially deprecated, [you should not be using them in new code](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Comment: HI @joeshmo, thank you for this. I'm aware that the code is using the deprecated functions. This is my last script to get working using MySQL. Once this is working I'll be changing all my script. But at least this will give a solid working copy to start with. Kind regards

Comment: Whenever you submit the form in loop last record of lid is always retrieved in $_POST['lid']. I dont think so you can do in this manner. Instead you have to place button and when its clicked, using javascript you need to get data of lid which is clicked.

Comment: Hi @Kamal, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post. The '$lid' is captured in my 'locationaction.php'. Which runs when the button is clicked. My sincere apologies to all. I should have included this in my original post. It is now added. Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After considerable time spent researching this on the Internet, I found the solution [here](http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/first-data-row-submit-button-doesn-t-work-in-while-758827.html). I was then able to edit this to suit my needs to the following script:

```
<?php

                    $query = "SELECT  l.*, COUNT(f.locationid) totalfinds FROM detectinglocations l LEFT JOIN finds f ON f.locationid = l.locationid WHERE l.userid = '$idnum' GROUP BY l.locationname";
                    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('error');
                    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);              
                    extract($row); 

                    /* Display Users in a table */ 
                    echo "<table cellspacing='5' border='0' cellpadding='0' width=95%>"; 
                    echo "<tr><td colspan='0' style='text-align: Left'></td></tr>\n"; 
                    echo "<tr><td style='font-weight: bold; 
                        font-size: 1.0em'>Location</td><td style='font-weight: bold; 
                        font-size: 1.0em'>Address</td><td style='font-weight: bold;  
                        font-size: 1.0em'>Finds Made</td></tr>\n";
                    mysql_data_seek($result, 0);

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {


                    /* display row for each user */ 
                        echo "<tr>\n"; 
                        $theID = $row['locationid']; 
                        echo " <td>{$row['locationname']}</td>\n"; 
                        echo " <td>{$row['returnedaddress']}</td>\n"; 
                        echo " <td>{$row['totalfinds']}</td>\n"; 
                        echo " <td><form action= locationsaction.php  method= 'post'><input type='hidden' name='lid' value=$theID />
                                    <input type= 'submit' name= 'type' value= 'View/Amend Location Details'/><input type= 'submit' name= 'type' value= 'Add/View Find Images'/><input type= 'submit' name= 'type' value= 'View Location Finds'/><input type= 'submit' name= 'type' value= 'View Location Finds'/></form></td>\n"; 
                        echo "</tr>\n"; 


                    }
                    ?>
```

Comment: This is a good approach. You could make it a little more flexible by giving your inputs unique names and checking for presence rather than contents. I wouldn't trust the text to stay consistent over the years. http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/html-form-submit.phtml

Comment: Hi @BrianNickel, thank you for this. I have used the approach your links suggests before and it works well. As you say this may be something I may need to consider later down the line. Thank you once again and kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Check out your Query. Since you have hardcoaded the query

```
$query = "SELECT  l.*, COUNT(f.locationid) totalfinds FROM detectinglocations l LEFT JOIN finds f ON f.locationid = l.locationid WHERE l.userid = '27' GROUP BY l.locationname";
```

as in the location id and the userid. This is an assumption since I cannot see them behaving them as variable. Rather they are string. Just have a look.

Comment: Hi @Shiv Kumar Ganesh, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post. I've checked the query independently adding a variable rather than a hard coded value, and unfortunately I still get the same problem. Kind regards

Comment: @IRHM how does your query fetch $idnum ? as in from where I cant see it on the page? :(

Comment: @IRHM I can see location Id in the hidden input but what about the userid mentioned as $idnum in the query ?

Comment: Hi @Shiv Kumar Ganesh, thank you for your continued help with this. The '$idnum' is a session id which is retrieved at an earlier point on my page. I didn't want to post a huge chuck of code, but rather the section that I was having problems with. My apologies if this hasn't helped. Kind regards

Comment: @IRHM sorry I am unable to solve out till now and asking multiple questions. But still tell me when you get the value of the $idnum from the session, it does have only one value. When you click post only that session value is being evaluated rather than the userID of the user next to whom you have clicked right? That is why the value of user stored in $idnum is always shown and you only see the previous data rather than new data because no related data is passed when submit is clicked. Hope I answered it correctly. If not please point out.

Comment: Hi @Shiv Kumar Ganesh, thank you for your reply. My apologies if I've not made this clear. I'll try to explain. User 'A' logs on. He looks at the page to see the list of locations. The locations he sees will only be pertinent to him. This is where the $idnum variable is used. Each location listed has it's own unique ID this is called the 'locationid`. Each location record has a button next to it which allows the user to view further details about the location. The page that the user sees need to show the details from the location record which they've selected. I hope this helps. Kind regards

Comment: @IRHM You are always getting the first locations result right ?

Comment: @IRHM if so pls let me know.I have the solution if this is the problem.

Comment: @IRHM I guess whichever button is clicked the first data goes by post, as in the location ID because you never associated any data with the button. As in the button dosent know which LOcationID cata to send. I hope you have to use a JavaScript so as to associate the location id with each button and send it as data whenever the post event happens. I guess I got it right this time ;)

Comment: Hi @Shiv Kumar Ganesh, thank you for your continued help with this and I'm sorry I didn't get back to you straight away. I was offline for a little while. I'll try to illustrate what's happening. If I have a list of 3 locations. Each location row has a button. If I click the button on the first row, I see the record details for last location in the list. The same applies if I click on the button in the second row. The details i see are for the last record. I hope this helps. Kind regards

Comment: @IRHM I m sorry :( either I dont understand or there is something goin on which is a bit trivial. I am not having any idea since even after discussing I wasnt able to find where the flaw is Sorry again! :)